# How to create an alias composed of many commands?

Tags: linux, bash

Commands are:

```sh
git checkout master
git remote add upstream git@github.com:minio/console.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master
```

What I want is to type one word and get all of them executed

Comment: From the documentation circa 1996: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.".  Don't use aliases.  They've been effectively deprecated for over 2 decades.

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an alias that executes multiple commands, simply by using the `;` to separate the comamnds: `git checkout master ; git remote ...`

But then, consider to simply write a small helper script instead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything special. Just put all the commands in the alias.

```
alias aliasname='git checkout master
git remote add upstream git@github.com:minio/console.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

File: `~/.zshrc` <--- Warning: This is not `bash`, please use `.bash_profile` accordingly to fit your needs!

Content:

```sh
function updateForkedConsoleRepo() {
    git checkout master
    git remote add upstream git@github.com:minio/console.git
    git fetch upstream
    git rebase upstream/master
    echo "git push if all goes well"
}
```

> Now with one word you can execute all your commands:

```sh
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ updateForkedConsoleRepo
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to details. You are recommending a zsh solution to a BASH question. Sure, in this case the syntax is the same, but still: some naive bash user might come along, and follow your guidance verbatim. So that user ends up with a .zshrc in his home directory for no reason at all.

Comment: You are totally correct @ghostcat, I did not noticed the `bash` tag here. Let me warn the user to use proper file for this matter!